# Pointer to Error: Linking Error in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

Following is  my code...

```
    #include"PointerToArray.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void display(const int (*displayM)[10],int resultRow,int resultColumn)
{

for(int i=0;i<resultRow;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<resultColumn;j++)
    {
         cout<<displayM[i][j];
    }
}

}

void read()
{
 int (*matrixA)[10],(*matrixB)[10];
 int row1,col1,row2,col2;
cout<<"Enter the number of rows and colums for Matrix1";
cin>>row1>>col1;
matrixA=new int[row1][10];
cout<<"Enter elements"<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<row1;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<col1;j++)
    {
         cin>>matrixA[i][j];
    }
}

cout<<"Enter the number of rows and colums for Matrix2";
cin>>row2>>col2;
matrixB=new int[row2][10];
cout<<"Enter elements"<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<row2;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<col2;j++)
    {
         cin>>matrixB[i][j];
    }
}

display(matrixA,row1,col1);



}
```

I am getting error as

> 1:1>C:\Progs\PointerToArray\Debug\PointerToArray.exe : fatal error
>   LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals 2:1>PointerToArray.obj : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl display(int
>   (*)[10],int,int)" (?display@@YAXPAY09HHH@Z) referenced in function
>   "void __cdecl read(void)" (?read@@YAXXZ)

Can any one suggest the way?

Comment: The code compiles fine for me using gcc 4.6.1

Comment: I am trying microsoft vc++...its not workoing

Comment: @user654761 if you copy-paste the exact same code you posted here in a new project, excluding the first include, it does compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The display function signature in your .c file is different from your error message in that there is no 'const' there.  Can you check that in PointerToArray.h the function declaration (prototype) does not have

```
void display(int (*displayM)[10],int resultRow,int resultColumn)
```

but

```
void display(const int (*displayM)[10],int resultRow,int resultColumn)
```

instead?

If it does you can resolve it by changing either one to match.

Comment: WHOA!!! Psych powers. That's it! The declaration doesn't match the definition, so the compiler is choosing the version without const. Too bad I can only upvote once. :)

Comment: Glad that's it.  Lucky guess :)